# Access Denied While Connecting to local SQL database in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

This is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Before Connect");
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("After Connect");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

And for some reason, it is giving me this error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FileIO\FileIO\bin\Debug\Database.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: In my case, make sure Database in the connection string is pointed to a real database.

Answer (score 1):

--->> **"Access is denied."**

Fix your folder/file access permissions:

1) Determine the identity that your code is running as.

2) Make sure that identity has appropriate access to folder and file.

Comment: Well, maybe it is, I just don't know how to address that?.. :(

Comment: Error 5 is almost for the permission thing. so you need to assign permissions to access the file.Secondly in your connection string you have written AttachDBFileName as well as Database. what are they both for?

Comment: @Qasim Javaid Khan : I already mentioned permissions 3 hours prior to your comment.